# Android app auto increment a value by 1 with some delay

Tags: android

This is a part of an app that I am trying to make. I am trying to make a delay that can be set by the user so after each +1 it delays with 500 milliseconds, but soon I figured that i don't even know how to add a simple build in delay, I tried with `delay(1000);` it gave me `Can not resolve method delay(int)` then with `sleep(1000);` same error, then with TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); and `Thread.sleep(1);` nothing worked I am missing something fundamental, maybe I need to import something ? this is the whole program

```
 if (v == swt1){

            while (counter<2100000000) {
                counter++;
            }
            scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
```

Activity:

```
package counter.test.my.simplecount;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.TypedValue;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Switch;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.graphics.Color;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    Switch swt1;
    TextView textTitle;
    EditText scoreText;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        swt1 = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        scoreText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);


        textTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 34);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btn1){
            counter++;
            scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
        if (v == btn2){
            counter--;
            scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        if (v == btn3){
            counter = 0;
            scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            if (v == swt1){

                while (counter<2100000000) {
                    counter++;
                }
                scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: An active wait is the worst thing to do and a sleep on the main thread the second worst. Use a Handler like mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Handler()` for delay like

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //Your Aftre delay code
            }
        },500);
```

Remember to import this:

`import android.os.Handler;`

Answer (score 3):

Use the "Handler" with "Runnable" to auto increment a value continuously at some time delay. Here i used "1sec" time dealy.

Find below code snippet for your requirement.

```
Runnable runnable;
Handler handler;
int delayTimeSec = 1000; //1 Sec
handler = new Handler();

runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //  Your auto increment logic...
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayTimeSec);
    }
}

handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayTimeSec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use thread instead of handler if you have got background tasks.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
///background calculations
try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
//main thread task to update user interface
            }
        });
}
}).start();
```